# Error: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined during Maven Install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-6

I have this function throwing weird error when I try to do a "mvn install"

```
public <T> T get(final AN_ENUM key)
{
    return some_map.get(key);
}
```

This is the line where I get the error

```
final int value = get(AN_ENUM.A_FIELD);
```

And this is the error in maven:

```
XXX.java:[25,41] type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; 
  no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with 
  upper bounds int,java.lang.Object
```

I know already how to "fix it". I just need to change the `int` to `Integer` in my last code sample and the bug goes away. It tell me that maven, for some sort of reason is not able to cast an Integer as an int when I use a type parameter.

**My Question is.. why ?**

In eclipse, using the same JDK, I have been able to run my application without any kind trouble nor warning.

- JDK 1.6
- Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2
- Maven 3.0.4

Comment: What's the source level in the maven compiler plugin in the POM.xml?  Is it set to less than 1.5?

Comment: What happens if you compile with javac?  You might find this is a discrepancy between ECJ and javac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `pom.xml`, set the target version to at least 1.5:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This way, Maven will use JDK 1.5 (or you can set it to 1.6 if you want).

Comment: Ok, I undestand how to fix the problem but I wonder why it does not compile.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue and it turns out that I was attempting to return a "boolean"(Primitive) and not a "Boolean"(Object).  Since you're trying to set it to an "int"(primitive) it will end up failing.

Try changing your "int" to an "Integer" and hopefully that should fix it.